CARLA tutorial: roslaunch ImportError: No module named util
I am a beginner in ROS and CARLA. I set up Carla ROS Bridge package using the steps mentioned in https://carla.readthedocs.io/projects/ros-bridge/en/latest/run_ros/ after installing ROS bridge from the Github repository.
When I am trying to run ROS bridge using command roslaunch carla_ros_bridge carla_ros_bridge.launch, I am receiving this error.
... logging to /home/carla-sim/.ros/log/bbb68f3c-f518-11ee-aad8-0242ac110002/roslaunch-cef764316090-3253.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://cef764316090:41235/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /carla_ros_bridge/ego_vehicle_role_name: ["hero", "ego_veh...
 * /carla_ros_bridge/fixed_delta_seconds: 0.05
 * /carla_ros_bridge/host: localhost
 * /carla_ros_bridge/passive: False
 * /carla_ros_bridge/port: 2000
 * /carla_ros_bridge/register_all_sensors: True
 * /carla_ros_bridge/synchronous_mode: True
 * /carla_ros_bridge/synchronous_mode_wait_for_vehicle_control_command: False
 * /carla_ros_bridge/timeout: 2
 * /carla_ros_bridge/town: Town01
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    carla_ros_bridge (carla_ros_bridge/bridge.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3277]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to bbb68f3c-f518-11ee-aad8-0242ac110002
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3303]
started core service [/rosout]
process[carla_ros_bridge-2]: started with pid [3310]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/carla-ros-bridge/catkin_ws/src/ros-bridge/carla_ros_bridge/src/carla_ros_bridge/bridge.py", line 24, in <module>
    import carla
  File "/opt/carla-simulator/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.15-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/carla/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    
  File "/opt/carla-simulator/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.15-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/carla/libcarla.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/opt/carla-simulator/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.15-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/carla/libcarla.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: No module named util
================================================================================REQUIRED process [carla_ros_bridge-2] has died!
process has died [pid 3310, exit code 1, cmd /root/carla-ros-bridge/catkin_ws/src/ros-bridge/carla_ros_bridge/src/carla_ros_bridge/bridge.py __name:=carla_ros_bridge __log:=/home/carla-sim/.ros/log/bbb68f3c-f518-11ee-aad8-0242ac110002/carla_ros_bridge-2.log].
log file: /home/carla-sim/.ros/log/bbb68f3c-f518-11ee-aad8-0242ac110002/carla_ros_bridge-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[carla_ros_bridge-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

I searched it in the internet and found some answers which were for python2.7 version, but I am using python3.7.
/usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.7


I assume this is what you found. This looks like you need to build the python API. https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/3889 You likely need to adapt their solution to python3 from python 2.
Another related question was here: https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/3374#issuecomment-735717927
If you'd like more help, please edit your question to show all the steps to reproduce your problem including what your base system is and anything that you've installed or setup in your environment for this.
Also please edit to include the potential references you've found and what you've tried to do to resolve the issue.
